# 405 POST method not allowed. No actions exist for this page

Tags: typescript, forms, svelte, sveltekit

I've been trying to do a small Form using the kit feature [Actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions), The issue is that when I submit the form I always get "405 POST method not allowed. No actions exist for this page". My code it's simple.

```
/form/+page.server.ts

import type { Actions } from './$types';
import {error} from '@sveltejs/kit'

  export const actions: Actions = {
    contact: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
        console.log(request.formData);
    },
    
} satisfies Actions;
```

and

```
/form/+page.svelte

<form method="POST" action="?/contact" class="w-full">

<input
id="name"
name="name"/>
<labelfor="name">name</label>

<input
id="email"
name="email"/>
<labelfor="email">email</label>

<input
id="phone"
name="phone"/>
<labelfor="name">phone</label>

</form>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong or what I am missing.

I've read the documentation and I'm expecting some king of help or guidance

Answer (score 0):

"request.formData" is supposed to be :

- Asynchronous
- A method

meaning your log should be:

```
console.log(await request.formData());
```

I guess it messes around with sveltekit :)

Here is an simple example from the official tutorial with minimal named form action :https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/named-form-actions

Comment: questioning forms for "progressive enhancement". It messes every time when using layouts, cross-side requests and a lot of headache with +page.server.ts and +page.ts